# log4j2 - keep last 7days of log file

Tags: log4j2

To keep the last 3days of log file with each file size up to 10MB, how to configure in log4j2.yml file?

I tried,

```
filePattern: ${log}/${app}-archive/${app}-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log"
...
Policies:
  TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
   interval: 1
   modulate: true
  SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
   size: 10 MB
 DefaultRolloverStrategy:
   delete:
    basePath: "${log}/${app}-archive"
    maxDepth: 1
    IfFileName:
     glob: "*.log"
    IfLastModified:
     age: 3d
```

and it creates only up to 7 archives on the same day and delete old files even though it was today's log. Is there a way to keep as much as files if its lastModified < 3d?
like app-04-09-2021-8.log, app-04-09-2021-9.log,....app-04-09-2021-39.log and so on.

Please, guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `DefaultRolloverStrategy` will keep at most the value of the `max` configuration attribute, `7` by default, per time based rollover interval, daily in your use case as indicated in your file pattern, `${app}-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log` - the `max` attribute only applies only to the `%i` counter.

Provide a bigger value for that attribute, the value you consider appropriate depending on your log patterns. For example:

```yaml
DefaultRollOverStrategy:
  max: 100
  delete:
    basePath: "${log}/${app}-archive"
    maxDepth: 1
    IfFileName:
     glob: "*.log"
    IfLastModified:
     age: 3d
```

Please, see the relevant [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html).

Comment: You are welcome Julia. I am happy to hear that the answer was helpful.

Comment: This answer is technically correct but a bit misleading. The max attribute applies ONLY to the %i component of the file name. By increasing from 7 to 100 we are indicating we can keep up to 100 files per time-based rollover interval (1 day in this case). Many people think it will limit the total number of files, not the number of files per interval.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification @rgoers, it is perfectly fine. I thought it was clear from the context of the question, but I have included the information in the answer. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @rgoers Sorry I didn't mention it, but it's a pleasure to meet you and an honor to receive your feedback on your library: I have been working with log4j and log4j2 my whole life, thank you very much. I will be glad to contribute to your project if I ever have the opportunity.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. However I will be the first to admit that some of what I consider to be the best parts of Log4j2 were written by others. It truly has been a team effort. So any contributions you would choose to make would be very welcome.

Comment: Thank you very much @rgoers. You're welcome, but sincerely, I want to thank you all the times that your library helped me to solve the problems of our applications. Of course, I will try to find open issues and other ways to contribute to the project if I can. I hope to see you soon.