# log4j2 delete old logfiles IfAccumulatedFileSize instead of new logfiles

Tags: log4j2

i use the following log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile
                name="MainLogFile"
                fileName="${sys:solr.log.dir}/solr.log.json"
                filePattern="${sys:solr.log.dir}/solr.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.json">
            <EcsLayout serviceName="my-solr"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 KB"/>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
                <Delete basePath="${sys:solr.log.dir}" maxDepth="1">
                    <IfFileName glob="solr.log.*.log.json">
                        <IfAny>
                            <IfAccumulatedFileSize exceeds="100 KB" />
                        </IfAny>
                    </IfFileName>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <!-- Use <AsyncLogger/<AsyncRoot and <Logger/<Root for asynchronous logging or synchonous logging respectively -->
        <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.hadoop" level="warn"/>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.solr.update.LoggingInfoStream" level="off"/>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.zookeeper" level="warn"/>
        <!-- HttpSolrCall adds markers denoting the handler class to allow fine grained control, metrics are
             very noisy so by default the metrics handler is turned off to see metrics logging set DENY to ACCEPT -->
        <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall" level="info">
            <MarkerFilter marker="org.apache.solr.handler.admin.MetricsHandler" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
        </AsyncLogger>

        <AsyncRoot level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="MainLogFile"/>
        </AsyncRoot>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

what i would want is that older logfiles are deleted if the accumulated size is exceeded. but log4j2 deletes the most recently modified files first. https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html says that there is a pathSorter parameter to do that. can someone tell me how to specify the reverse sort logic as is the default?

Comment: Please, see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67028910/log4j2-keep-last-7days-of-log-file/67028967#67028967).

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to have been the default-max-value for the DefaultRollingPolicy

using

```
<DefaultRolloverStrategy min="1" max="9999999">
                <Delete basePath="${sys:solr.log.dir}" maxDepth="1">
                    <IfFileName glob="solr.log.*.log.json">
                        <IfAny>
                            <IfAccumulatedFileSize exceeds="100 KB" />
                        </IfAny>
                    </IfFileName>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
```

it works as expected